# Azure Functions, http request gets second last value back

Tags: node.js, function, http, azure

I'm creating an Node.js API with TypeScript which I want to host in Azure Functions. It sends requests to another public API. I got it to work but it has a bug which I can't resolve.
I'm sending an http post request to my API with Postman. In the body of the request there is a JSON object with one property "id".

But I don't get the last value back as a response. I get the second last value as a response. Assume the first request with id "1" gets "good" as a response. The second request with the id "2" gets a "good" as a response, too. But it should get "bad" as a response. The third request with the id "3" gets as a "bad" as response but it should get "good". The fourth request with the id "4" gets "good" as a response but it should get "bad".

The problem just exsits in my API. When I send requests directly to the another API via Postman, I don't get this problem.

index.js

```
module.exports = function (context, req) {

if (req.body.checkID) {
    api.validationStatus(req.body.checkID)
    .then(function (resp) {
        if (resp.validated) { // Number is correct
            context.log('Result: good');       
            res = { body: "Result: good" }              
        }
        else if (resp.name === "StatusCodeError") { // Number is not correct
            context.log('Result: bad ' + resp.name);
            res = { body: "Result: bad " + resp.name }   
        }
        else if (resp.name === "RequestError") { // API is not reachable
            context.log('Result, bad ' + resp.name);
            res = { body: "Result, bad " + resp.name }  
        }
        else { // Something else went wrong
            context.log("Result, bad.");
            res = { body: "Result: bad." }  
        }
    }); 
}
else {
    res = {
        status: 400,
        body: "Please pass an id"
    };
}

context.done(null, res);};
```

api.js

```
myApi.prototype.validationStatus = function (id) {
    // Request options
    var options = {
        method: 'get',
        url: this.config.validationStatusLocationUrl.replace("{id}", id),
        headers: { "Authorization": this.config.apiKey }
    };
    // Request with a promise
    return reqpromise(options)
        .then(function (res) {
        return JSON.parse(res);
    })
        .catch(function (err) {
        return err;
    });
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I got it. The solution is simple and I assume I know why it had this behavior.
The context.done(); needs to be executed in the .then-Section of the promise (in the if and the else section). The problem was that I was sending a response even when the current api request (api.validationStatus()) was not finished yet (async, round robin style) and so I got just the old value of the previous requests.

index.js

```
module.exports = function (context, req) {

    if (req.body.checkID) {

        api.validationStatus(req.body.checkID)
        .then(function (resp) {
            if (resp.validated) { // Number is correct
                context.log('Result, good.');       
                context.res = { body: "Result, good." }    
            }
            else if (resp.name === "StatusCodeError") { // Number is not correct
                context.log('Result, bad: ' + resp.name);
                context.res = { body: "Result, bad." + resp.name }   
                context.done();   
            }
            else if (resp.name === "RequestError") { // API is not reachable
                context.log('Result, bad: ' + resp.name);
                context.res = { body: "Result, bad." + resp.name }
                context.done();   
            }
            else { // Something else went wrong
                context.log("Result, bad.");
                context.res = { body: "Result, bad." }  
                context.done();   
            }
            context.done();
        }); 
    }
    else {
        context.res = {
            status: 400,
            body: "Please pass an id"
        };
        context.done();
    }
};
```